# How to get additional $_GET Parameters in Yii2 when prettyurl is enabled?

Tags: php, paypal, yii-url-manager

how can i get additional $_GET Parameters in Yii2 even when prettyurl is enabled?

I need to read some feedback from the redirect Paypal-Link but i cant change the Link-Format on Paypal-Side to fit my Yii2 implementation:

http://example.com/controller/action?success=boolean&token=xyz

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can use it

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-requests.html

for e.g

if you need to use *$_GET['success']* or *$_GET['token']*

you must use  it:

```
$request = Yii::$app->request;

$get = $request->get();

$success = $request->get('success');
$token= $request->get('token');
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way:

```
$url = parse_url(Yii::$app->request->url);

parse_str($url['query'], $array);

$success = $array['success'];
$token = $array['token'];
```

but it still doesnt seem like the right Yii2-ish way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html this will help You. you can specify GET POST method for any controller,

```
[
'dashboard' => 'site/index',

'POST <controller:\w+>s' => '<controller>/create',
'<controller:\w+>s' => '<controller>/index',

'PUT <controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'    => '<controller>/update',
'DELETE <controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/delete',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'        => '<controller>/view',];
```

for example

```
'POST <controller:\w+>/<success:\w+>/<token:\w+>'    => '<controller>/update',
```

Comment: thanks, but i cannot tell paypal to redirect to http://example.com/controller/boolean/xyz

Comment: URL rewrite management is run in your Yii2 .if You  give Url like http://example.com/controller/action?success=boolean&token=xyz it will convert to friendly url using Your Url rewrite management

Comment: but it is already rewritten. the original app is like: index.php?/controller/action?success=boolean&token=xyz. the now "friendly" address is example.com/controller/action?success=boolean&token=xyz. is it possible that the last part will be rewritten, too? or am i missing a point?

Comment: give link to  paypal using this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html link. it will manage

Answer (score 0):

Use the Request class.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html

`print_r(Yii::$app->request->get());` returns all get variables in an array.  It's like doing `print_r($_GET);` in straight php.

If you want a specific $_GET variable you access it as follows:

```
Yii::$app->request->get('varName');
```

In your case it would be:

```
$success = Yii::$app->request->get('success');
$token = Yii::$app->request->get('token');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my successful returnUrl from paypal which yii2 handles beautifully with prettyurl enabled in the UrlManager.

http://multi2.myhost/subscription/subscription/success?token=EC-8GE539098H175763M

I have created a subscription module and a controller class called SubscriptionController and actions called actionSuccess and actionCancel.

The Paypal redirect only passes one parameter. The token. No need for two parameters. Your success and cancel returnurl's should be something like:

controller/action  or subscription/success/

controller/action  or subscription/cancel/

Your success returnUrl:

SubscriptionController/actionSuccess($token)

```
public actionSuccess($token)
{

}
```

and your cancel returnUrl:

SubscriptionController/actionCancel($token)

```
public actionCancel($token)
{

}
```

Using this method there is no need for a second parameter to handle the success and cancel variable since the separate Controller Actions solve this problem. Incorporate the 'success' in the name of the action which satisfies PrettyUrl Management.

You will have to modify both merchant preference returnUrls in the following code.

```
$merchantPreferences = new MerchantPreferences();
         $merchantPreferences->setReturnUrl($model->merchant_preference_returnurl)
                ->setCancelUrl($model->merchant_preference_cancelurl)
```

There is therefore no need for:

```
$request = Yii::$app->request;
$get = $request->get();
$token = $request->get('token');
```

at the beginning of the action.